# INNO SETUP - Skip/Hide uninstall finished message

Tags: inno-setup, messagebox, uninstallation

I've created an "Uninstall finished" custom form to be displayed at the end of uninstall process.

This works very well, but I still get the end finished uninstall default MessageBox from the uninstall engine.
It's the MessageBox with the 'UninstalledAll' ressource:

> %1 was successfully removed from your computer.

I've searched for a solution to Hide/Skip this message but didn't find any.

Any idea?

Comment: The only (yet simple) option I can see here is forceful termination of the process which is no good.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yeah, that's what I thought, so I tried 'Abort' function in CurUninstallStepChanged (case usPostUninstall), but it doesn't work...Is there another way to forceful termination? I mean without an external killprocess function.

Comment: Exceptions are handled for the `usPostUninstall` step, so this is not an option. I meant terminating process through the WinAPI, but it's bad because the uninstaller won't clean itself. There is no easy and clean solution for this (safest would be building your own Inno Setup, safe but ugly could be e.g. hooking `MessageBox` API function from an external library).

Comment: Ok, that what I thought. I prefer a clean setup on each step of the process, so I will keep it like that. In my case, 2 notification messages is best than no message at all!

Comment: I looked at the source and the only thing that will suppress the message are the Silent and VerySilent command line options. If a restart is required VerySilent is needed to suppress that. Neither of those help you, but I just wanted to check for myself. Best you can do is request that option for future builds.